# Volumen in Riemannian manifold, coordinates change

Tags: riemannian-geometry, change-of-variable

I reading the following thread

[Is orientability needed to define volumes on riemannian manifolds?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674525/is-orientability-needed-to-define-volumes-on-riemannian-manifolds)

But I don't understand the following steps

> $$\int_{\boldsymbol x^{-1}(R)}\sqrt{\det H(\boldsymbol y^{-1}\circ \boldsymbol 
>  x(p))}|J|\,dx_1\dots dx_n=\int_{\boldsymbol y^{-1}(R)}\sqrt{\det H(p)}\,dy_1\dots dy_n,$$

How can I do that $|J|$ don't appear in the right hand of the equation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the classical integration by substitution
$$
\int_{U} f\circ \varphi |\det (d\varphi)|dx_1\cdots dx_n = \int_{\varphi(U)} f dy_1\cdots dy_n  
$$
when $\varphi \colon U\to \varphi(U)$ is a diffeomorphism and $f\colon U \to \Bbb R$ is integrable.
Here $f = \sqrt{\det H}$, $\varphi =y^{-1}\circ x$, and $U=x^{-1}(R)$.
Notice that $J= \det \left(d(y^{-1}\circ x)\right)$.

Comment: Thanks @Didier.